# What's that material on the Varda capsule that looks like cake sugar icing?

Tags: reentry, identify-this-object, materials

Watching and listening to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWxl921rMgM) amazing footage of the Varda capsule's atmospheric re-entry, what is the nature and role of the material used on the parts not subjected to the high temperatures of atmospheric re-entry? it seems difficult to cure, one can see cracks on this image,

[image]

([source](https://www.marketplace.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/IMG_5635.jpg?w=740))

and difficult to apply, one can see what looks like fingerprints(?) on this one

[image]

([youtube screenshot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWxl921rMgM))

Comment: It looks like refractory cement over ceramic fibre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the FAA document [Environmental Assessment
for Reentry, Landing, and Recovery Operations
of a Varda Space Industries Capsule within
Utah Test and Training Range (UTTR) South or
Northern Dugway Proving Ground (DPG), Utah](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/20240214-Varda-at-UTTR-Reentry-Final-EA.pdf) it is a "densified oxidized polyacrylonitrile (OPAN) felt"

> The Varda capsule is approximately 3 ft in diameter, 2.5 ft tall, and weighs less than 200 pounds (lb) (Figure
> 2.1-1 and Figure 2.1-6). It is a 45<sup>o</sup> sphere aluminum cone with a spherical aft body as an aeroshell. The 45<sup>o</sup>
> cone is aerodynamically stable in all flight regimes and if perturbed it quickly returns to low angles of
> attack. The primary thermal protective shield is a heat shield material developed by NASA: conformal
> phenolic impregnated carbon ablator (CPICA). The back-shell would experience less heat and would use a
> densified oxidized polyacrylonitrile (OPAN) felt as its thermal protective shield.

Comment: sounds *delicious!*